# jQuery Animating a stickman to jump (animate top, then bottom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm making this kind of game. It's just a stickman that "walks" around the screen. I want to add jumping to it if you press "up".

Here's my code (without the jump):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var sitting = $('#sitting'),
                image = $('#img');
            sitting.hide();
            $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
                    arrow = {
                        left: 37,
                        up: 38,
                        right: 39,
                        down: 40,
                        space: 32
                    };
                switch (keyCode) {
                case arrow.left:
                    if (!sitting.is(':visible')) {
                        image.add(sitting).stop(true).animate({
                            left: '-=60px'
                        }, 300, "linear");
                    }
                    break;
                case arrow.up:
                    break;
                case arrow.right:
                    if (!sitting.is(':visible')) {
                        image.add(sitting).stop(true).animate({
                            left: '+=60px'
                        }, 300, "linear");
                    }
                    break;
                case arrow.down:
                    break;
                case arrow.space:
                    image.fadeToggle(-100, function () {
                        sitting.fadeToggle(-100);
                    });
                    break;
                }
            });
            $('#sit').click(function () {});
        });
```

Out of common sense, I used queued animations and did this (I cut down to only case arrow.up because it's the only relevant part):

```
case arrow.up:
                    if (!sitting.is(':visible')) {
                        image.animate({
                            top: '+=10px'
                        }, 200, "linear");
                        image.animate({
                            bottom: '+=10px'
                        }, 200, "linear");
                    }
                    break;
```

For some reason, it's not working. What so ever. Here's the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iwigeg/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iwigeg/5/)**</kbd>

```
var sitting = $('#sitting'),
    image = $('#img'), // COMMA HERE 
    jumping = false ;  // ADD THIS
```

and modify:

```
    case arrow.up:
    if (!sitting.is(':visible') && jumping===false) {
        jumping = true;
        image.stop().animate({
            top: '-=150px'
        }, 200, "linear", function(){
          $(this).animate({top: '+=150'}, 300,'linear', function(){
             jumping = false;
          });                 
        });
    }
    break;
```

Comment: That doesn't keep it's original position, it sends it all the way to the bottom of the page.. :s

Comment: @DoorKnob hope was useful and you understand it... If not, just ask

Comment: There's a problem, when you jump, it lands like above the ground (Around 50 pixels above) and you don't ever touch the ground again. Unless you refresh the page.